# Using TikZ with DokuWiki

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, notes

I am using DokuWiki to write my notes. The one thing that I am missing is the ability to plot. I would like to use TikZ to fill this need, but I have been unable to get exactly what I want. I am using the [Latex plugin for Dokuwiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin%3alatex).

The preamble used by the plugin is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{MyColour}{rgb}{1.00,0.50,0.00}

{\color{MyColour}
```

I tried using this [example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/parabola-plot/):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\shade[top color=blue,bottom color=gray!50] 
  (0,0) parabola (1.5,2.25) |- (0,0);
\draw (1.05cm,2pt) node[above] 
  {$\displaystyle\int_0^{3/2} \!\!x^2\mathrm{d}x$};

\draw[style=help lines] (0,0) grid (3.9,3.9)
   [step=0.25cm]      (1,2) grid +(1,1);

\draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (4,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-0.2) -- (0,4) node[above] {$f(x)$};

\foreach \x/\xtext in {1/1, 1.5/1\frac{1}{2}, 2/2, 3/3}
   \draw[shift={(\x,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {$\xtext$};

\foreach \y/\ytext in {1/1, 2/2, 2.25/2\frac{1}{4}, 3/3}
   \draw[shift={(0,\y)}] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {$\ytext$};
\draw (-.5,.25) parabola bend (0,0) (2,4) node[below right] {$x^2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Unfortunately, the image is produced, but it is tiny! The content of the is cropped such that the majority of the image is missing I have no idea how to fix this and I have been unable to get the size to change at all. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Increase the `scale` parameter after `\begin{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: Hello mafp. I have attempted to change the scale, but this does not change the size of the image only the scale of the contents of the image.

Comment: I cannot reproduce any clipping with an up to date system running pdflatex, can you improve your question? Right now, i am voting to close as unclear.